# JPA JSF Assign value to a null object

Tags: jsf, jpa

Good Afternoon in my timezone.

I am working on a web application, that uses both JSF and JPA.
There is one screen that contains multiple checkBoxes , something like this:

```
 option1   check1  check2
 option2   check1  check2
 option3   check1  check2
```

In the database the query to retrieve the values of the checkboxes uses one LEFT JOIN (this is business logic) to retrieve the checkbox values:
   Select * FROM Option LEFT OUTER JOIN CheckBoxType ....

The class diagram is something like this:

```
  class Option
       String label
       checkBoxType checkBox

  class CheckBoxType
       boolean value;
```

The final result is , it could exist a list of "Option" in which some contains the checkBox variable to NULL.

In the JSF we use the following code:

```
<ui:repeat var="assocCheck" value="#{checkBean.getOptions}">
      <h:selectBooleanCheckBox name="#{assocCheck.label}" value="#{assocCheck.checkBox.value}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

To present the results there is no problem, in the case of the "Option" objects that contains the checkBox to null the checkbox on the screen appers with NO value , when i set to true one of this checkboxes and try to save them, the JSF throws a exception telling me the following

```
javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: ....xhtml @45,126 value="#{assocCheck.checkBox.value}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
```

I understand why this is happening , what is the best manner to deal with a problem like this ?Could adding a valueChangeListener on the checkbox(every time a checkbox is full filled there is a method on the bean that creates the checkBox object) be the best approach ?

Thanks in advance 
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a lazy setter / getter in your Option class:

```
@Entity
public class Option {
    @...ToOne(optional = true, ...)
    private CheckboxType checkbox;

    public boolean isCheckboxChecked() {
        return checkbox != null && checkbox.getValue();
    }

    public void setCheckboxChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (checkbox == null) {
            if (!checked) {
                // No need to create a CheckboxType
                return;
            }
            checkbox = new CheckboxType();
        }
        checkbox.setValue(checked);
    }
}
```

Now you can use that one in your JSF page:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckBox name="#{option.label}" value="#{option.checkBoxChecked}"/>
```

Why I would use this approach: It keeps the business logic attached to the business object. Especially the implicit statement *`checkbox == null` means the same as `checkbox.value == false`* is made explicit.

BTW: I would rename `Checkbox.value` to `Checkbox.checked` - from my point of view it makes things clearer: `checkbox.isChecked()` vs. `checkbox.getValue()` (or even worse `checkbox.isValue()`).